# How do you use variable as key in Dataweave

Tags: mule, dataweave, anypoint-studio

```
output application/json

var name = vars.uname
---
{
    
   vars.name: name, //-----> Here i am not able too retreive variable as key
   
   description: payload.text
    
    }
```

[for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPxL6.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use parenthesis in the key to specify that is an expression.

```
output application/json

var name = vars.uname
---
{
    
   (vars.name): name, //-----> Here i am not able too retreive variable as key
   
   description: payload.text
    
}
```

Comment: Awesome.. Thanks for quick reply